# Nginx: location 404 with try_files under a different root directory

Tags: nginx

I'm in the process of moving a wiki I administer (practicalplants.org) to a new server running Nginx. I'm accustomed to Apache; this is my first time working with Nginx and I'm having trouble adapting the rewrites and aliases I had set up in Apache. The directory layout is as follows

```
/html               (server root)
    /html/w         (mediawiki)
    /html/community (vanilla)
    /html/blog      (wordpress)
/sso                (Zend Framework SSO solution)
    /sso/public
```

As you can see, the sso solution has it's own publicly accessible application root directory, which I'm attempting to set as the `root` for the `location` directive, but it seems like the following `try_files` still attempts to fall back to the `server root`.

Here's my config:

```
server {
  server_name practicalplants.org;

  root /var/www/v-practicalplants/html;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/practicalplants.org-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/practicalplants.org-error.log;

  include /etc/nginx/biowikifarm_listen80_443.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/biowikifarm_generics.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/biowikifarm_generic_php.conf;

  disable_symlinks off;

  location = / {
    # Redirect domain-only access to wiki:
    rewrite "^[/]?$" /wiki/ permanent;
  }

  location /wiki {
    #rewrite "^/wiki[/]?([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))?" /w/index.php?title=$1&$args last;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /w/index.php?title=$uri&$args;
  }
  location /w/media {
    location ~ ^/w/media/thumb/(archive/)?[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ {
      try_files $uri @thumb_w;
    }
  }
  location @thumb_w {
    rewrite ^/w/media/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ /w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2;
    rewrite ^/w/media/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ /w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params; fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/w/thumb.php; fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
  }

  location /sso {
    root /var/www/v-practicalplants/sso/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php
  }
}
```

This config gives me a 404 if I navigate to /sso

Is there something obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `alias` instead of `root` here.

Your existing configuration tries to load `/var/www/v-practicalplants/sso/public/sso/index.php`, which is probably not what you want. Regardless of which `location` it's in, `root` always specifies the document `root`, i.e. the location of `/`.

Use `alias` instead to specify the location of the `location`.

```
location /sso/ {
    alias /var/www/v-practicalplants/sso/public;
    try_files.....
```